# Non descriptive jQuery Ajax error

Tags: jquery, ajax, error-handling

I have been struggling with a very weird jQuery ajax error users have reported.
I cant reproduce it but multiple users seem to have problems with it.
For debugging I added the following fail function to the $.post request:

```
function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
  $(".statusbox").html(textStatus + "," + errorThrown + "," + jqXHR.status + "," + jqXHR.statusText + "," + jqXHR.responseText);
}
```

Users report getting `error,,0,error,undefined` as an error, which is about as non-descriptive as it might get.

I cant find anything in the server logs as well. The script makes a post request to a cgi-bin script, the full code is here: https://donorwetreferendum.nl/s/teken.js

Does anyone recognize this error behavior?

Comment: An error code of 0 usually means that the request was cancelled in progress, or there was a data serialisation issue before sending.

Comment: Try to use $.ajax() instead of $.post(). It could give more info about failurs while request processing.

Comment: I changed the script to use the ajax function. I tried disabling the network between filling in the form, and i get the same non descriptive error, is this normal when there is no internet?

Comment: Still the same error :-(

Answer (score 0):

I've seen http status = 0 when page script stops, for example user clicked history-back, or refreshed page, or stopped loading the page.

Is your page loaded completely (including all ads, counters, etc) before user clicks stop?

Comment: please someone convert this answer to comment